# Raphael - what is the native delay function to draw circles?

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am using Raphael, to draw 3 circles. how to i make the circles draw each one by one with some time gap?

I know there is a option with settimeout, but apart from is there any native function to make delay to draw the circles?

my simple code:

```
<div id="paper"></div>

var paper = Raphael('paper',500,500);

var c1 = paper.circle(50,50,25);

var c2 = paper.circle(100,50,25);

var c3 = paper.circle(150,50,25);
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/R96pv/)

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is native way, You can use `Element.animate()` with call backs or for delays you can use `Animation.delay()`....[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R96pv/4/)